# How to derive the dynamics of $S_t$ in the Vasicek model?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

I’m a grad quant student and I’m struggling with this model

$$dX_t = k(\mu-Χ_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$$

I’m given this Vasicek model
And after applying Itô's lemma with
$$S_t = e^X$$

$$\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=[k(\mu-\ln(S_t))+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2]d_t+\sigma dW_t $$

They get to this equation

$$ S_t = e^{\ln(S)e^{-k(t-s)}+ \mu \left(1-e^{-k(t-s)}\right)+\sigma\int_{s}^{t}e^{-k(t-u)}\,dW_u}$$

And I’ve got no clue how to derive this last equation after Itô's lemma, could anyone enlighten me? No intermediate steps are shown in my professor's slides.

Comment: It looks like you change notation, I think the first line should be $dS_t = k(\mu-S_t)dt+\sigma dW_t$.  I don't know about the method they used since it doesn't make much sense to me.  For a hint for a different method: try computing $d(e^{kt}X_t)$.

Comment: In this example X has been used instead of S , and to solve ittos lemma e^X has been used indeed

Comment: Okay, I don't think it makes much sense to use $e^X$.  I would suggest you try computing $d(e^{kt}X_t)$.

Comment: Ok Thanks will try that

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, let $g(x,t) = e^{kt}x$. The relevant derivatives are:
$$\begin{align*}
g_t(x,t) &= ke^{kt}x \\
g_x(x,t) &= e^{kt} \\
g_{xx}(x,t) &= 0 
\end{align*}$$
Applying Itô's lemma to $S_t = g(X_t, t)$, we get:
$$\begin{align*}
dS_t &= ke^{kt}X_t dt + e^{kt} dX_t \\
&= ke^{kt} X_t dt + e^{kt}[k (\mu - X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t]  \\
&= k\mu e^{kt}dt + \sigma e^{kt} dW_t
\end{align*}$$
Thus,
$$S_t -S_0 = e^{kt} X_t - X_0 = \mu e^{kt} + \sigma \int_0^t e^{ks}dW_s$$
So that $$X_t = X_0 e^{-kt} + \mu + \sigma e^{-kt} \int_0^t e^{ks}dW_s$$

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration :)

Comment: @Anna Does the answer above answer your question? If so, please mark it accordingly.